# ElementMesh from Tetrahedron subdivision

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, mesh, finite-element-method

I would like to create a nice "structured" `ElementMesh` made of `TetrahedronElement` by dividing one larger `Tetrahedron`. One example of such procedure (see below) is given in documentation for [`Tetrahedron`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tetrahedron.html). It recursively splits the original tetrahedron and therefore the number of elements per edge is a power of 2.

```
(* From documentation page on Tetrahedron *)
SymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl_], k_] /; 0 <= k < 2^Length[pl]:=Module[
  {n = Length[pl] - 1, i0, bl, pos},
  i0 = DigitCount[k, 2, 1]; 
  bl = IntegerDigits[k, 2, n];
  pos = FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1 + {0, 1}, #1 + {1, 0}] &, {0, i0},Reverse[bl]];
  Tetrahedron@Map[Mean, Extract[pl, #] & /@ Map[{#} &, pos + 1, {2}]] 
]

NestedSymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl_],level_Integer]/;level==0:= Tetrahedron[pl]
NestedSymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl_],level_Integer]/;level>0:= Flatten[
  NestedSymmetricSubdivision[SymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl], #],level - 1] & /@ Range[0, 7]
]

Graphics3D[
 NestedSymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[{{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}}],3],
 BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.5]
]
```

[image: tetrahedraGraphics3D]

This is nice, but I would like to split the tetrahedron in such way that it has arbitrary number of elements per edge (not only 2, 4, 8, etc) and generate `ElementMesh` object from them.

---

For completeness, this is my function for creating `ElementMesh` for subdivision procedure from [`Tetrahedron`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tetrahedron.html) documentation.

```
(* Helper function to determine TetrahedronElement orientation *)
reorientQ[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := Positive@Det[{a - d, b - d, c - d}]    

tetrahedronSubMesh[pts_, n_Integer] := Module[
  {f, allCrds, nodes, connectivity},
  f = If[reorientQ[#], #[[{1, 2, 4, 3}]], #] &;
  allCrds =f /@ (Join @@ List @@@ NestedSymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pts], n]); 
  nodes = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[allCrds, 1];
  connectivity = With[
    {rules = Thread[nodes -> Range@Length[nodes]]},
    Replace[allCrds, rules, {2}]
    ];

  ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> nodes,
   "MeshElements" -> {TetrahedronElement[connectivity]}
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with slightly convoluted solution that uses various transformations on `ElementMesh` object with help of [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package (at least version [0.5.0](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools/releases/tag/v0.5.0)).

First we create uniform structured mesh on unit cube (`Cuboid[]`) with `n` elements per edge.

```
Get["MeshTools`"]
n = 3;
unitCubeMesh = CuboidMesh[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {n, n, n}];
```

Then split the hexahedral mesh to tetrahedra (`HexToTetrahedronMesh`), taking care that element edges coincide, and select only elements below body diagonal plane of unit cube. We already get unit tetrahedron with `n` elements per edge.

```
unitTetMesh = SelectElements[
  HexToTetrahedronMesh[unitCubeMesh],
  #1 + #2 + #3 <= 1 &
]

unitTetMesh["Wireframe"[
  Axes -> True,
  "MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue
]]
```

[image: UnitTetMesh]

To extend this procedure we calculate `TransformationFunction` between corners of arbitrary tetrahedron and unit tetrahedron and apply this transformation to `ElementMesh`.

```
SeedRandom[42]
corners = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {4, 3}]

tf = Last@FindGeometricTransform[
   corners,
   {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
   Method -> "Linear"
]

mesh = TransformMesh[unitTetMesh, tf]

Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"[
   Axes -> True,
   "MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue
 ]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[corners]}]
]
```

[image: RandomTetMesh]