# Custom 3d histogram

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, histograms

so I wondered if there is a way to use histogram list such that it doesn't bin in quadrat mode, but given a set of 3D points, could bin over a tessellation of some regular tetrahedrons/hexagons/spheres?

Comment: [This might finally help someone](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1474/605). (It was originally written due to an embarrassing misunderstanding.)

Comment: Amazing! I'm going to see if I can make it work in 3D, thanks @Szabolcs

Comment: Can itgeneralise to 3D? and with the tally function, can we only make it tetrahedral, with colours defined by transparency instead?

Comment: You might consider `SmoothKernelDistribution`.  It works in all dimensions.

Comment: In 3D, this could in principle be opaque right? because you would be looking at regions hidden within some volume that already has points in it - I guess you would need an opacity option on the distribution somehow

Comment: Actually I think it would be best to bin in terms of tetrahedrons

Comment: I see the Sierpinski mesh https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SierpinskiMesh.html and wonder if this is possible

Comment: Seems related! https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167819/elementmesh-from-tetrahedron-subdivision

Comment: Can you tile space with tetrahedra? [I don't think it's possible.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron_packing)

Comment: You can and I just did it, I will forward it on in an hour or so!

Comment: No, it's not possible to tile space with identical tetrahedra.

Comment: I mean sure, if you don't allow them to flip right. But if some are flipped, its like a 3d Zelda symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
th = Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/6, Sqrt[6]/3}}];
bins = N @ NestedSymmetricSubdivision[th, 3];
centers = RegionCentroid /@ bins;
nf = Nearest[centers -> "Index"];

SeedRandom[1]
rp = RandomPoint[Cuboid[], 3000];
tF = FindGeometricTransform[th[[1]], Tetrahedron[][[1]]][[2]];
transformed = tF /@ (Normalize[#, Total[#]/Max[#] &] & /@ rp);
Row[{Graphics3D[{Blue, Point@rp, Opacity[.05], Cuboid[]}, ImageSize -> 400], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Point@transformed, Opacity[.05], th}, 
   BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

```
groups = GatherBy[transformed, nf[#, 1] &];
tallies = {Rescale[Length /@ groups], bins[[nf[#[[1]], 1]]] & /@ groups};
Show[Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], th, 
   Transpose[{FaceForm[Opacity[Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {0.05, .25}], Blue]]&/@#, #2}&@@tallies]},
  Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> 1], 
 ListPointPlot3D[groups, PlotStyle -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reversed"}]/@ tallies[[1]])],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, your skills know no bounds, massive massive thanks for figuring these out!

Comment: Thank you @MKF for the kind words.

Comment: I feel I was little help that's all

Comment: In any case, truly amazing @kglr

Comment: @MKF, thank you for the accept. Btw, can I suggest that you revisit some of your older questions to check if any of the answers are worth accepting?

Comment: sure which ones?

Comment: @MKF, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/186801/125), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191298/125), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192530/125), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190853/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188356/125) have answers.

Comment: thank you, all sorted

Comment: by the way, how is `tetrahedron` defined for you? its just `th` right?

Comment: @MKF, yes; thank you. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, just a response to the previous comment

```
SymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl_], k_] /; 0 <= k < 2^Length[pl] :=
  Module[{n = Length[pl] - 1, i0, bl, pos}, i0 = DigitCount[k, 2, 1];
  bl = IntegerDigits[k, 2, n];
  pos = FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1 + {0, 1}, #1 + {1, 0}] &, {0, i0}, 
    Reverse[bl]];
  Tetrahedron@Map[Mean, Extract[pl, #] & /@ Map[{#} &, pos + 1, {2}]]]

NestedSymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl_], level_Integer] /; 
  level == 0 := Tetrahedron[pl]
NestedSymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl_], level_Integer] /; 
  level > 0 := 
 Flatten[NestedSymmetricSubdivision[
     SymmetricSubdivision[Tetrahedron[pl], #], level - 1] & /@ 
   Range[0, 7]]

Graphics3D[
 NestedSymmetricSubdivision[
  Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[
     3]/6, Sqrt[6]/3}}], 3], BaseStyle -> Opacity[0], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: The mesh I wish to histogram over]

Comment: So the question is the following now, is there a way to convert this into a mesh, and tally all the points inside each mini tetrahedron, so that each tetrahedron has different opacity based on the number of points inside each region?

Comment: My guess is yes using `ListDensityPlot3D[HistogramList[pts, 10][[2]], DataRange -> the region of the tetrahedron]` but with the above converted into a mesh somehow

Comment: These are all tetrahedra, but they are not identical. Some have a different shape than others. When you mentioned histogram, I assumed you wanted identical shapes (possibly flipped or rotated), something in analogy with a 2D triangular lattice.

Comment: My bad, Sorry for the confusion! I want to basically implement the technique you have somehow to the tetrahedron layout above; actually I think these are all identical up to reflections...

Comment: So if you plot a bunch of points in 3D which lie inside each mini tetramino, it does a very similar thing to `ListDensityPlot3D[HistogramList[pts, 10][[2]], DataRange -> the region of the tetrahedron]`, or equivalently your tally function. The feature I want to change is not colour however, but opacity of each tetramino

Comment: You can easily find out if a point is in a tetrahedron using `RegionMember[Tetraherdon[{....}]][pointOfInterest]`. This would be easy to repurpose for tallying the points in each tetrahedron, though it might be slow.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how this would be implemented, for one if points lie inside a tetramino, how does mathematica know which volume its in?

Comment: I thought about it, and I think I have an idea...

Comment: Taking your own code, look at `Graphics3D /@ 
 NestedSymmetricSubdivision[
  Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {1/2, 
     Sqrt[3]/6, Sqrt[6]/3}}], 1]`. It's quite clear from simple visual inspection that the tetrahedra are not identical. We can verify that they have the same `Volume`, but not the same `SurfaceArea` or the same shape. Of course we can still use them for binning if we want to.

Comment: If you can determine a center for each cell (tetrahedron or other) such that the cell would be a Voronoi cell, then you can use the same approach as in the code I linked: use Nearest to determine which cell each binned point belongs to.

Comment: They are not the same shape? I need to check this xD thanks for the headsup! Maybe its just the angle, but they look symmetric to me...

Comment: Exactly that was my idea also to borrow your hexagonal method

Comment: Damn - they aren't symmetric :(

Answer (score 0):

So I have some random points that lie in the tetrahedron, [image: Random points],

and also calculate the centres of the tetraminos using `Mean`.

I apply `indices = First /@ nf /@ cloud` as in @Szabolcs code and now want to bin the points in each tetramino bin.

Here is histogram of the indices to check things are happening

[image: Histogram]

I have tried

```
tally = Tally[indices];

ListDensityPlot3D[Join[cloud, List /@ Sort[tally][[All, 2]], 2],
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BeachColors"][1 - #] &)]
```

To bin the points but to no avail.

As for @N.J.Evans response, I define RegionMemberFunctions as

```
Map[RegionMember, NestedSymmetricSubdivision[
 Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[
    3]/6, Sqrt[6]/3}}], 3]];
```

But if I try to now tally/bin the points with

```
    Table[Map[regionmemberfunctions[[i]], cloud], {i, 1, 
   Length[NestedSymmetricSubdivision[
     Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[
        3]/6, Sqrt[6]/3}}], 3]]}];
```

It takes forever... Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think perhaps binning over the tetraminos and using something like this is great https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/3d-heatmap-density-plot

Comment: And maybe via `Which` or `Count` there could be some success